# FCGI throws warning

Tags: perl, cgi, fastcgi

I was trying to implement FASTCGI, from following **[tutorial](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Perl_FastCGI#Handing_off_request_fulfillment_to_a_fork.28.29ed_child)**.
Whenever I execute the code, I get following warning:

**Subroutine FCGI::DESTROY redefined at xyz.fcgi line 30.**

The statement, that is responsible for throwing the warning:

```
*FCGI::DESTROY = sub {};
```

Any idea, why it throw warning?

*I do not want to suppress the warning*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below are the cases which cause `Subroutine xyz redefined error`

1: You declared the same subroutine somewhere

2: [You have a dependency loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3429260/257635)

If it's not from above two cases then restarting the server and adding `1;` at the end of your module may solve the issue.

Also see: [best way to handle Subroutine redefined warning](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=890026)

Comment: The code over-rides the sub-routine defined in FCGI module. Reason -1 was correct. Thanks